# How to Customize JAXB Marshalling if generating JAXB beans from XML

Tags: jaxb

I want to customize the marshalling of dates in JAXB. It's a variant of this already asked [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343669/how-to-let-jaxb-render-boolean-as-0-and-1-not-true-and-false). I would think I would use an XMLAdapter, as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343669/how-to-let-jaxb-render-boolean-as-0-and-1-not-true-and-false/1633006#1633006) questions specifies.

But I can't do that exactly, because I'm going the other way around, generating the JAXB beans from an .XSD -- I can't add annotations to the JAXB beans because they are generated code.

I've tried calling Marshaller.setAdapter(), but with no luck.

```
            final Marshaller marshaller = getJaxbContext().createMarshaller();
            marshaller.setSchema(kniSchema);
            marshaller.setAdapter(new DateAdapter());
            ...
            private static class DateAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, XMLGregorianCalendar> {
            @Override
            public String marshal(XMLGregorianCalendar v) throws Exception {
              return "hello"; //Just a test to see if it's working
            }
            @Override
            public XMLGregorianCalendar unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
              return null; // Don't care about this for now
            }
}
```

Where the relevant part of my generated JAXB bean looks like this:

```
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "date")
    protected XMLGregorianCalendar activeSince;
```

When I do this, what the default date/XMLGregorianCalendar marshalling happens. It's as if I didn't do it all.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Charles