# JAXB - Suppress Boolean attribute if false

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling

Let's say that I have a class

```
@XmlRootElement(name="thing")
public class Thing{
    private String name;
    private boolean awesome;

    @XmlValue public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return this.value;
    }


    @XmlAttribute public void setAwesome(boolean awesome) {
        this.awesome = awesome;
    }
    public boolean isAwesome() {
        return this.awesome;
    }
}
```

If I create some things, then marshall them to XML, it looks like this:

A flying ninja:

```
<thing awesome="true">flying ninja</thing>
```

A regular old popcorn ball:

```
<thing awesome="false">popcorn ball</thing>
```

But... what I would like to do is change the way that my boolean attributes are marshalled.  I would rather see the popcorn ball look like this, supressing the awesome attribute:

```
<thing>popcorn ball</thing>
```

How can I do this?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead, and a member of the JAXB 2.X ([JSR-222](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222)) expert group.

Using MOXy you can do the `XmlAdapter` approach as suggested by [Hovercraft Full Of Eels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6552740/jaxb-suppress-boolean-attribute-if-false/6553765#6553765).  It would look something like:

**BooleanAdapter**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class BooleanAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Boolean, Boolean> {

    @Override
    public Boolean unmarshal(Boolean v) throws Exception {
        return Boolean.TRUE.equals(v);
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean marshal(Boolean v) throws Exception {
        if(v) {
            return v;
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

**Thing**

You associate your property with the `XmlAdapter` using the `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotation as follows:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlValue;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

@XmlRootElement(name="thing")
public class Thing{
    private String name;
    private boolean awesome;

    @XmlValue public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }


    @XmlAttribute
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(BooleanAdapter.class)
    public void setAwesome(boolean awesome) {
        this.awesome = awesome;
    }
    public boolean isAwesome() {
        return this.awesome;
    }
}
```

**Demo**

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Thing.class);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        Thing thing = new Thing();
        thing.setName("popcorn ball");

        thing.setAwesome(false);
        marshaller.marshal(thing, System.out);

        thing.setAwesome(true);
        marshaller.marshal(thing, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<thing>popcorn ball</thing>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<thing awesome="true">popcorn ball</thing>
```

**Using the JAXB RI**

If you run this example with the JAXB RI you will get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Adapter example.BooleanAdapter is not applicable to the field type boolean. 
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at @javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter(type=class javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter$DEFAULT, value=class example.BooleanAdapter)
        at public boolean example.Thing.isAwesome()
        at forum251.Thing
```

**For More Information**

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html
- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/07/xmladapter-jaxbs-secret-weapon.html
- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2011/05/jaxb-and-joda-time-dates-and-times.html

Comment: It is a shame that it won't work in the RI.  But your answer is very thorough, and got me to an appropriate solution.  Thanks.

Comment: It does work in JAXB RI if you change the method signature slightly to use `Boolean` instead of `boolean`. At least for getters this approach worked for me. I've not tested it with setters like in you example.

Answer (score 3):

Achieve this by using a nullable type, and registering a JAXB listener to your class. Within the JAXB listener, set your attribute to `null` if you dont want to marshal it. This approach should work in any JAXB implementation.

### Your (Boolean or other) attribute

```
@XmlAttribute(required = false)
private Boolean valueUnknown;
```

### The JAXB beforeMarshal handler

```
@SuppressWarnings("PMD")
private void beforeMarshal(final Marshaller marshaller) {
    // Remove the "valueUnknown" attribute if it is not true.
    // Assigning a null value implies that the attribute is removed.
    if(!valueUnknown) {
        valueUnknown = null;
    }
}
```

This approach can - for instance - yield the result below. Note that the attribute valueUnknown is only present when no value attribute is given.

```
    <items>
        <item xsi:type="eduDataExchange:compoundValue" valueUnknown="true"/>
        <item xsi:type="eduDataExchange:compoundValue" value="4" percentage="3"/>
    </items>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with JAXB (yet), but generally this sort of thing should be quite doable with [XSLT processing](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JAXPXSLT6.html) or transforming.

Also, this question's answer mentions use of an XmlAdapter which looks to be directly applicable to your problem: [How to let JAXB render boolean as 0 and 1, not true and false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343669/how-to-let-jaxb-render-boolean-as-0-and-1-not-true-and-false)

Answer (score 0):

replacing boolean with Boolean Object , it solved this issue for me .

Use :-

```
private Boolean awesome;
```

instead of :-

```
private boolean awesome;
```

Comment: Yeah, but that's a bummer, because I don't want "null" to be an option anywhere else in my code.