# JAXB issue parsing all caps boolean

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm fairly new to JAXB and am having a bit of trouble figuring out how to fix this the correct way.

I have some XML that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ParameterValueStruct xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Name>ROOT.Object.SubObject</Name>
  <Value xsi:type="xsd:boolean">TRUE</Value>
</ParameterValueStruct>
```

But my JAXB Unmarshaller gives me a Struct which returns **null** for getValue(). I expected this to return **true**.

Changing **TRUE** in my xml to **true** works. Is there a way to make my Unmarshaller parse "xsd:boolean" **TRUE** into a Java boolean correctly?

For simplicity, here is my stripped down class and the code for unmarshalling:

```
@XmlRootElement ( name="ParameterValueStruct" )
public static class ParameterValueStruct 
{ 
    @XmlElement(name = "Name", required = true)
    protected String name;
    @XmlElement(name = "Value", required = true)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "anySimpleType")
    protected Object value;

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public Object getValue() { return value; }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
{
   JAXBContext c = JAXBContext.newInstance(ParameterValueStruct.class);
   Unmarshaller u = c.createUnmarshaller();

   byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("test.xml"));
   ParameterValueStruct struct = (ParameterValueStruct) u.unmarshal(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
   System.out.println(struct.getName()+" "+struct.getValue()); // issue here
}
```

Here's the output, leaving the XML as **TRUE**

```
ROOT.Object.SubObject null
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a new custom adapter for marshaling and unmarshaling of boolean values. There are multiple ways to do so. [You can check this thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343669/how-to-let-jaxb-render-boolean-as-0-and-1-not-true-and-false)

Just remember one thing you will have to handle for all data types and values u are going to accept for marshaling as well as unmarshaling

Also you can read through this page

[Java XML and JSON Binding](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xmladapter-jaxbs-secret-weapon.html)

Comment: I've added the class I want to unmarshal to plus provided code that should fully compile -- value can be any object and uses @XmlSchemaType(name = "anySimpleType"). Can you update your answer st it fits my situation in a clean way?

Comment: I did not get you. You can also edit my answer to your satisfaction. Do you want me to put a precise solution for your class.